# Looping through a javascript array to check each item for certain children elements

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to loop through a webpage and change certain styles depending on the number of children with the class 'award-winner' within elements with the class 'award-winner-wrapper'. Currently, I have been able to check the webpage for the parent elements using this.

```
<div class="award-winner-wrapper">
    <h2>Heading></h2>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <div class="award-winner'></div>
</div>

<div class="award-winner-wrapper">
    <h2>Heading></h2>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <div class="award-winner'></div>
</div>

<div class="award-winner-wrapper">
    <h2>Heading></h2>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <div class="award-winner'></div>
    <div class="award-winner'></div>
</div>

let parents = document.querySelectorAll('.award-winner-wrapper');
let pArray = Array.from(parents)
```

The problem I having is using a foreach loop to check each array item for the 'award-winner' class and if there are 2 or more elements with that class change some styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate over your `parents` NodeList (here using [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)) and query the parent for relevant children here with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and adding a class with [`classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
let parents = document.querySelectorAll('.award-winner-wrapper');

parents.forEach(parent => {
  if (parent.querySelectorAll('.award-winner').length > 1){
    parent.classList.add('winner');
  }
});
```

```css
.winner {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="award-winner-wrapper">
    <h2>Heading></h2>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <div class="award-winner"></div>
</div>

<div class="award-winner-wrapper">
    <h2>Heading></h2>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <div class="award-winner"></div>
</div>

<div class="award-winner-wrapper">
    <h2>Heading></h2>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <div class="award-winner"></div>
    <div class="award-winner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I feel real dumb - it's been a long time since I've worked with JS like this. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Heh, no worries. Glad it helped.